# Excel IF statement range and highlight

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with the `IF` statement below, I want to check if value in cell is present in the given range and then highlight it with red color.

```
=IF(D10=(B3:BH3),"found","not found")
```

It always returns not found for me.

Comment: `=IF(CountIf(B3:BH3,D10),"found","not found")`

Comment: it worked, thank you, can you help me with highlighting the cell in red ?

Comment: actually your formula will work too if you enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `If` like that. You must count the number of occurances of the value in the given range, and if there is none then the value is not found, i.e.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B3:BH3, D10), "Found", "Not Found")
```

Comment: i thought it's like python or any other programming language, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Select `B3:BH3` > `Home` tab > `Conditional Formatting` > `New Rule...` > Use a Formula to ...> enter this formula :

```
= B3 = $D$10
```

Select the colors and formatting and OK

Comment: can i include it in the IF statement somehow ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you try it? The conditional formatting formula  will be adjusted because of the relative reference.

Comment: oh, you want to highlight only `D10`? Then select just `D10` and the conditional formatting formula will be `=CountIf(B3:BH3,D10)`

Answer (score 0):

The closest to your formula that provides the correct result is this:

=IF(OR(D10=(B3:BH3)),"found","not found")

But you need to enter it as an [Array formula](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) (i.e. you hold down the **ctrl** and **shift** keys when you press enter after editing the formula.

In effect what the array formula does is it works through each of the items in the array (B3:BH3) and evaluates whether each of the values are equal to D10. Adding in the **OR** means that it returns true if any of the values are equal to D10. Without it, it will only return a true result if ALL the values are equal to D10.